# Mysql View : Issue when Providing userdefined datatype in creating VIEW with if statement

Tags: mysql, view, sql-view

```
 desc user_roles;
+------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field      | Type       | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+------------+------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id         | int(50)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| user_id    | int(50)    | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| role_id    | int(50)    | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| created_at | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                             |
| updated_at | timestamp  | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| status     | tinyint(3) | YES  |     | 1                 |                             |

create or replace view bff_user_roles as select user_roles.id as id,  
user_id as user_id, role_id as role_id, updated_at as updated_at, status as status,
IF(created_at ='0000-00-00 00:00:00', "1990-01-01 23:59:59", created_at)
 as created_at as timestamp from user_roles;

desc bff_user_roles;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| id         | int(50)     | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| user_id    | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| role_id    | int(50)     | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| updated_at | timestamp   | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| status     | tinyint(3)  | YES  |     | 1                   |       |
| created_at | varchar(19) | NO   |     |                     |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

The issue is here that when I go to create VIEW in MySql db then it is taking created_at column datatype as varchar . But it should be and required timestamp. I have tried to add explictly datatype but it is not working. I have taken if statment in VIEW due some legacy data  issue in user_roles table.

Comment: Why not fix your data?

Comment: Data modification not allowed in production specially for created_at column we don't know when excatly data inserted in table, but I have done changes for new data and make datatype for created_at as timestamp with default value current timestamp earlier it was varchar .. We need to create to report with old data also and we are creating VIEW for this ro replicate user_roles table data.

Answer (score 1):

`IF(created_at ='0000-00-00 00:00:00', "1990-01-01 23:59:59", created_at)` deals with 2 alternative values. One of them (`created_at`) is TIMESTAMP, and another one (`"1990-01-01 23:59:59"`) is VARCHAR(19). Server selects the most common format from those two, and it is VARCHAR(19).

You must use not string literal but [datetime literal](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

`IF(created_at ='0000-00-00 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '1990-01-01 23:59:59', created_at)`

In this case the most common datatype will be DATETIME.

Comment: It changes the data type into datetime. I wonder if it's possible to make it a timestamp?

Comment: TIMESTAMP '1990-01-01 23:59:59' should be TIMESTAMP( '1990-01-01 23:59:59')

Comment: Also timestamp is not a CAST option so I don't think it possible to set created_at in the view to timestamp https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: @P.Salmon Your variant is a function usage whereas my variant is a literal datatype specifier. See the link provided. Of course the effect is the same...

Comment: @blabla_bingo *I wonder if it's possible to make it a timestamp?* No. And this makes no sense.

Comment: @Akina Since it's a view which doesn't store actual values, so I suppose timestamp which has a shorter date range really has no byte-saving advantage over datetime in a view? Is that why you think it makes no sense?

Comment: @blabla_bingo I think that this makes no sense because: 1) calculated datetime value cannot have timezone/timeshift. 2) the server should process both datetime and timestamp values in the same inner format which is the most common one (datetime) or maybe some another which is more wide (unpacked datetime).